# XPath to get only children in <UL> structure

Tags: html, xpath

```
...
    <ul>
       <li>A
           <ul>
              <li>B
              </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>C
       </li>
    </ul>
...
```

What `XPath` expression will give only the child `<li>` elements of the outer `<ul>` element?  I don't want the grandchild `<li>` whose value is `B`.

So far I have `//ul[1]/li` but this is giving me the grandchild as well.

Comment: Why have you only accepted ***one*** answer to your last 30 or more questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the outer `ul`, and then select child `li` :

```
/ul/li
```

In case `ul` is not the root element in the actual HTML, or if you want to literally *select the outer `ul`* i.e `ul` that doesn't have ancestor other `ul` element, then you can do as follow :

```
//ul[not(ancestor::ul)]/li
```

If there is only one outer-most `ul` i.e the `ul` has no sibling `ul` or any other `ul` at the same level, you can use :

```
(//ul)[1]/li
```

Comment: @CJ7 `//ul[1]` returns every first `ul` element within parent element. It is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/ul[1]`

Comment: @CJ7 `(//ul)[1]/li` is probably closer to, if not exactly, what you want

Comment: This is correct, but I believe that OP is trying to leave out the child elements of the selected `li` elements.  (This is not possible.)

Comment: @kjhughes No I am not. You have invented that yourself. har07 understood the question.

Comment: @har07 Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @CJ7:  ***Then you should have accepted his answer!***

Answer (score 1):

**XPath is for selection, not transformation.**  You cannot create arbitrary XML with XPath; you can only select nodes in the input document as they appear (and pass those nodes to some functions).

***Therefore, you cannot select an element without its children.***

To select all `li` elements of the first `ul` (as har07 suggested):

```
(//ul)[1]/li
```

To select from those just their immediate text children:

```
(//ul)[1]/li/text()
```

Or just those immediate text children that are not just whitespace:

```
(//ul)[1]/li/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: The question is quite straightforward. har07 has understood it. Your answer is irrelevant.  I asked how to get the children elements and not the grandchildren elements.  Obviously the grandchildren will be included inside the children elements, but I don't want the grandchildren to appear as separate elements in the returned set of elements.

Comment: I also don't understand why you include the irrelevant stuff about `text()` and whitespace.

Comment: @CJ7: When you weren't accepting his answer, I tried to read between the lines to see what else you might have meant.   My apologies for misinterpreting, but if you didn't have such terrible answer acceptance practices, neither of would have had to waste further time on this.